# Firebase push notification - React Native: GULApplication.h file not found

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am running a project with React Native where I have used React Native Firebase Push Notification (react-native-firebase/messaging: "^7.1.8") and it was working till today.

But when I tried to install pod to create build today it started showing me this error when I try to run the project in xCode or via yarn.

`/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/GoogleUtilities/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.h:19:9: 'GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Private/GULApplication.h' file not found`

How come this has happened, I am using

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.3.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.1.8"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have also got this issue today. Downgrading pod version might work.<br>
I changed it to Firebase/Messaging (6.8.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all answers,
It was an upstream error which made the latest version corrupted GoogleUtilities 6.7.0.
Updating pod after 19 hours of the post, It solved the problem.
Now the GoogleUtilities is 6.7.1.

Ref: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3938